# jQuery looping through an object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

I have the following HTML and JS, I am trying to only display elements if they match the criteria selected in the `<select>` tags. I am fairly sure that my IF statement currently would not achieve what I am trying to do even if it did work, however I am struggling to think of the logic for this.

HTML:

```
<select id="price-from" class="form-control">        
    <option selected value="£500">£500</option>
    <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
    <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
    <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
    <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
    <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>

<p>To</p>

<select id="price-to" class="form-control">
    <option value="500">£500</option>
    <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
    <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
    <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
    <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
    <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
    <option selected value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var product1 = {title:"Cute Gnome", type:"Cute", price:"3999"};
    var product2 = {title:"Funny Gnome", type:"Funny", price:"5999"};
    var product3 = {title:"Seasonal Gnome", type:"Seasonal", price:"12999"};
    var product4 = {title:"Horror Gnome", type:"Horror", price:"7999"};
    var productArray = [
        product1, product2, product3, product4
    ];      
    var len = productArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ($("#price-from").val() < productArray[i].price && $("#price-to").val() > productArray[i].price){
            //Loop through code and only output objects between both price criteria
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? (F12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the change event to `select` elements. Additionally you should to convert string to `Number` before comparison.  use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var priceFrom = +$("#price-from").val(); //Convert value to Number
    var priceTo = +$("#price-to").val(); //Convert value to Number

    //Filter the elements which matches the condition
    var matchingElemets = productArray.filter(function(pd) {
        var p = +pd.price; //Convert value to Number
        return p >= priceFrom && p <= priceTo;
    });
    console.clear();
    console.log(matchingElemets);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var product1 = {
    title: "Cute Gnome",
    type: "Cute",
    price: "3999"
  };
  var product2 = {
    title: "Funny Gnome",
    type: "Funny",
    price: "5999"
  };
  var product3 = {
    title: "Seasonal Gnome",
    type: "Seasonal",
    price: "12999"
  };
  var product4 = {
    title: "Horror Gnome",
    type: "Horror",
    price: "7999"
  };
  var productArray = [
    product1, product2, product3, product4
  ];

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var priceFrom = +$("#price-from").val(); //Convert value to Number
    var priceTo = +$("#price-to").val(); //Convert value to Number
    var matchingElemets = productArray.filter(function(pd) {
      var p = +pd.price; //Convert value to Number
      return p >= priceFrom && p <= priceTo;
    });
    console.clear();
    console.log(matchingElemets)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price-from" class="form-control">
  <option selected value="£500">£500</option>
  <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
  <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
  <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
  <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
  <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
  <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
  <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>

<p>To</p>

<select id="price-to" class="form-control">
  <option value="500">£500</option>
  <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
  <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
  <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
  <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
  <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
  <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
  <option selected value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, both this and @Jamiec's answer appear to work. Would you be able to run through roughly what this is doing? I'm new to JS, and would love to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: @SixTailedFox Jamiec's answer  is very similar to mine only difference is conversion to number I have use `+` operator where as he used `parseInt()`

Answer (score 1):

You presumably want to do this whenever one of the `select` boxes is changed, so the thing to do is hook into the `change` event on both and run your code. You dont specify what you mean by "output" so I'll just output to the console.

```js
var product1 = {title:"Cute Gnome", type:"Cute", price:"3999"};
var product2 = {title:"Funny Gnome", type:"Funny", price:"5999"};
var product3 = {title:"Seasonal Gnome", type:"Seasonal", price:"12999"};
var product4 = {title:"Horror Gnome", type:"Horror", price:"7999"};
var productArray = [
    product1, product2, product3, product4
];      

$('select').on('change',function(){
   var from = parseInt($('#price-from').val(),10);
   var to = parseInt($('#price-to').val(),10);
   var matches = productArray.filter(function(x){
     var price = parseInt(x.price,10);
     return from <= price && to >= price;
   });
  console.clear();
   console.log(matches);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price-from" class="form-control">        
    <option selected value="£500">£500</option>
    <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
    <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
    <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
    <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
    <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>

<p>To</p>

<select id="price-to" class="form-control">
    <option value="500">£500</option>
    <option value="1000">£1,000</option>
    <option value="2000">£2,000</option>
    <option value="3000">£3,000</option>
    <option value="4000">£4,000</option>
    <option value="5000">£5,000</option>
    <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
    <option selected value="20000">£20,000</option>
</select>
```

Roughly what this code is doing is as follows

```
var from = parseInt($('#price-from').val(),10);
var to = parseInt($('#price-to').val(),10);
```

These two lines take the values of your two select boxes, and parse their value to an integer. See [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
var matches = productArray.filter(function(x){
 var price = parseInt(x.price,10);
 return from <= price && to >= price;
});
```

This line uses `filter` to get the items from your original list which fall within the range of prices selected. See [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
console.clear();
console.log(matches);
```

These lines simply clear and then output the items from the array which match your prices to the console. You could easily iterate over this list and output to the page iif required.

Comment: This seems to work just fine. By outputting I mean to display to the page :) Could you explain what this code is actually doing? I'm new to JS and would be grateful if you could help me understand it. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Code below add it to the onchange Attribute on both of the selects and you have a Framework Independent solution that Returns the list.

Ofcourse you will have to add your own logic to Change displayed products.

Do note that haveing a `.ready` doesnt really do annything here since it is (should be) an Event driven Action.

```
function filter()
{
//reduces calls to DOM in for loop
var min = document.getElementById("price-from").value;
var max = document.getElementById("price-to").value;

var length = productArray.length;
var products = [];

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (min <= productArray[i].price && max > productArray[i].price) {
        products.push(productArray[i]);
    }
}

return products;
}
```